# How can I use .docs.find in V9 Firebase - Next.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

This is currently what I have for Firebase v.8 but I need to understand how to implement it in V.9 so I can avoid receiving this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

```
function Sidebar() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const colRef = collection(db, 'chat');

  const userChatRef = query(
    colRef,
    where('users', 'array-contains', user.email)
  );
  const chatsSnapshot = userChatRef;

  const createChat = () => {
    const input = prompt('Please enter an email address');

    if (!input) return null;

    if (
      EmailValidator.validate(input) &&
      !chatAlreadyExists(input) &&
      input !== user.email
    ) {
      setDoc(doc(collection(db, 'chats')), {
        users: [user.email, input]
      });
    }
  };

  const chatAlreadyExists = (recipientEmail) => {
    !!chatsSnapshot?.docs.find(
      (chat) =>
        chat.data().users.find((user) => user === recepientEmail)?.length > 0
    );
  };
```

[image: Database for 'user']

Comment: Is users an array? Can you share a screenshot of that document?

Comment: I've just shared it.

Comment: Can you share some more code to give more context on chatsSnapshot? Does it contain documents from chats collection or just chat collection?

Comment: I just added the entire code snippet

Comment: Is the all the code? Do you have `getDocs()` to run the query and fetch the docs anywhere? Also how is `chatsSnapshot` accessible from `chatAlreadyExists`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Your comment was actually the answer, I haven't imported a react-firebase package that's why it wouldn't work. thank you.